# Shift select not working after upgrade

Tags: selection-tools, select

After upgrade I am unable to shift select multiple things. Not able to shift select multiple objects nor faces nor edges nor anything. Any ideas?

Update:

It works if I hold down alt (actually option since I am using a Mac), but then it also selects the whole loop in addition as shown in the picture.

[image: The loop was selected using shift + alt / option]

Comment: If you hold down Alt (or Option) together with Shift it's normal that a loop is added since that's the default way it should work. Since each function has its own shortcut it's possible that somehow for whatever reason the shortcut for adding a selection (Shift Left Mouse) has changed, but the shortcut for adding a loop selection (Alt Shift Left Mouse) is still working. Try looking in the preferences under "Keymap", "3D View". If there is no entry for "Select" with "Shift Left Mouse" then it was maybe deleted by accident. In this case there should be a "Restore" button to get back to default.

Comment: It seems like something had changed on my keymap. I restored my settings, and then things started working again. Thanks for leading my in the right direction :)